# Convert csv file into json file

Tags: python, json, csv

This is my first time asking a question using this platform but I always used it to solve my problems by reading questions similar to mine, but this time I could not find an answer.

[image]

The above CSV file contains 1395 rows, which is the file that I am working with.
I want to convert this CSV file into a JSON file using python. I want the JSON file to look like this:

```json
 {'data': [{'title': 'جمال خاشقجي',
   'paragraphs': [{'context': 'جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي (13 أكتوبر 1958، المدينة المنورة - 2 أكتوبر 2018)، صحفي وإعلامي سعودي، رأس عدّة مناصب لعدد من الصحف في السعودية، وتقلّد منصب مستشار، كما أنّه مدير عام قناة العرب الإخبارية سابقًا.',
     'qas': [{'question': ' - من هو جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي؟ ',
       'id': '969331847966',
       'answers': [{'text': 'صحفي وإعلامي', 'answer_start': 73}]},
      {'question': ' - متى ولد جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي وتوفي؟ ال',
       'id': '115150665555',
       'answers': [{'text': 'حمزة خاشقجي (13 أكتوبر 1958، المدينة المنورة - 2 أكتوبر 2018)،',
         'answer_start': 10}]},
      {'question': ' - في أي مدينة ولد جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي؟ ال',
       'id': '74212080718',
       'answers': [{'text': 'المدينة المنورة', 'answer_start': 39}]}]},
    {'context': 'جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي (13 أكتوبر 1958، المدينة المنورة - 2 أكتوبر 2018)، صحفي وإعلامي سعودي، رأس عدّة مناصب لعدد من الصحف في السعودية، وتقلّد منصب مستشار، كما أنّه مدير عام قناة العرب الإخبارية سابقًا. ويكتب عموداً في صحيفة واشنطن بوست منذ 2017، وُصف في الصحف وأجهزة الاعلام العالمية بأنه "وفيّ للدولة السعودية" و"منتقد لسياساتها".',
     'qas': [{'question': ' - في أي صحيفة قام بكتابة عمود منذ عام 2017؟ ال',
       'id': '465699296586',
       'answers': [{'text': 'واشنطن بوست', 'answer_start': 224}]},
      {'question': ' - كيف وصفها في الصحف ووسائل الإعلام الدولية؟ ال',
       'id': '564177542570',
       'answers': [{'text': 'وُصف في الصحف وأجهزة الاعلام العالمية بأنه "وفيّ للدولة السعودية" و"منتقد لسياساتها".',
         'answer_start': 246}]},
      {'question': ' - في أي منصب شغل في الجريدة؟ ال',
       'id': '98945395462',
       'answers': [{'text': 'وتقلّد منصب مستشار،', 'answer_start': 135}]}]},
    {'context': 'غادر خاشقجي السعودية في سبتمبر 2017، وكتب بعد ذلك مقالات صحفية انتقد فيها الحكومة السعودية. انتقد خاشقجي بصورة كبيرة ولي العهد السعودي محمد بن سلمان، والملك سلمان بن عبد العزيز. وكذلك عارض التدخل العسكري في اليمن.',
     'qas': [{'question': ' - متى غادر خاشقجي السعودية؟ ال',
       'id': '838329318053',
       'answers': [{'text': 'في سبتمبر 2017،', 'answer_start': 21}]},
      {'question': ' - لمن ينتقده في مقالاته الإخبارية؟ ال',
       'id': '432910739583',
       'answers': [{'text': 'الحكومة السعودية.', 'answer_start': 74}]},
      {'question': ' - لمن انتقد خاشقجي بشدة في مقالاته الإخبارية؟ ال',
       'id': '619452973730',
       'answers': [{'text': 'ولي العهد السعودي محمد بن سلمان، والملك سلمان بن عبد العزيز.',
         'answer_start': 117}]}]}]},
  {'title': 'السعودية',
   'paragraphs': [{'context': 'السعودية أو (رسميًا: المملكة العربية السعودية) هي دولة عربية، وتعد أكبر دولة في الشرق الأوسط وتقع تحديدًا في الجنوب الغربي من قارة آسيا وتشكل الجزء الأكبر من شبه الجزيرة العربية إذ تبلغ مساحتها حوالي مليوني كيلومتر مربع.',
     'qas': [{'question': ' - أي دولة هي أكبر دولة في الشرق الأوسط؟ ال',
       'id': '333772766499',
       'answers': [{'text': 'المملكة العربية السعودية)', 'answer_start': 21}]},
      {'question': ' - أين تقع المملكة العربية السعودية في آسيا؟ ال',
       'id': '262204981583',
       'answers': [{'text': 'الجنوب الغربي', 'answer_start': 109}]},
      {'question': ' - ما هي مساحة الجزء الأكبر من شبه الجزيرة العربية؟ ال',
       'id': '809283218984',
       'answers': [{'text': 'حوالي مليوني كيلومتر مربع.',
         'answer_start': 194}]}]},
    {'context': 'السعودية ورسميًا المملكة العربية السعودية هي أكبر دولة في الشرق الأوسط وتقع تحديدًا في الجنوب الغربي من قارة آسيا وتشكل الجزء الأكبر من شبه الجزيرة العربية إذ تبلغ مساحتها حوالي مليوني كيلومتر مربع. يحدها من الشمال العراق والأردن وتحدها الكويت من الشمال الشرقي، ومن الشرق تحدها كل من قطر والإمارات العربية المتحدة بالإضافة إلى البحرين التي ترتبط بالسعودية من خلال جسر الملك فهد الواقع على الخليج العربي، ومن الجنوب تحدها اليمن، وعُمان من الجنوب الشرقي، كما يحدها البحر الأحمر من جهة الغرب.',
     'qas': [{'question': ' - ما هي الحدود في الشمال؟ ال',
       'id': '130251388427',
       'answers': [{'text': 'يحدها من الشمال العراق والأردن',
         'answer_start': 199}]},
      {'question': ' - ما هي الحدود في الشمال الشرقي؟ ال',
       'id': '791276760553',
       'answers': [{'text': 'الكويت', 'answer_start': 237}]},
      {'question': ' - ما هي الحدود في الشرق؟ ', ....
```

But what I am getting is this:

```
[{'title': 'جمال خاشقجي', 'paragraphs': [{'context': 'جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي (13 أكتوبر 1958، المدينة المنورة - 2 أكتوبر 2018)، صحفي وإعلامي سعودي، رأس عدّة مناصب لعدد من الصحف في السعودية، وتقلّد منصب مستشار، كما أنّه مدير عام قناة العرب الإخبارية سابقًا.', 'qas': [{'question': ' - من هو جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي؟ ', 'id': '959884094657', 'answers': [{'text': 'صحفي وإعلامي', 'answer_start': 73}]}]}]}]
[{'title': 'جمال خاشقجي', 'paragraphs': [{'context': 'جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي (13 أكتوبر 1958، المدينة المنورة - 2 أكتوبر 2018)، صحفي وإعلامي سعودي، رأس عدّة مناصب لعدد من الصحف في السعودية، وتقلّد منصب مستشار، كما أنّه مدير عام قناة العرب الإخبارية سابقًا.', 'qas': [{'question': ' - متى ولد جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي وتوفي؟ ال', 'id': '734996283548', 'answers': [{'text': 'حمزة خاشقجي (13 أكتوبر 1958، المدينة المنورة - 2 أكتوبر 2018)،', 'answer_start': 10}]}]}]}]
[{'title': 'جمال خاشقجي', 'paragraphs': [{'context': 'جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي (13 أكتوبر 1958، المدينة المنورة - 2 أكتوبر 2018)، صحفي وإعلامي سعودي، رأس عدّة مناصب لعدد من الصحف في السعودية، وتقلّد منصب مستشار، كما أنّه مدير عام قناة العرب الإخبارية سابقًا.', 'qas': [{'question': ' - في أي مدينة ولد جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي؟ ال', 'id': '876483484251', 'answers': [{'text': 'المدينة المنورة', 'answer_start': 39}]}]}]}]
[{'title': 'جمال خاشقجي', 'paragraphs': [{'context': 'جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي (13 أكتوبر 1958، المدينة المنورة - 2 أكتوبر 2018)، صحفي وإعلامي سعودي، رأس عدّة مناصب لعدد من الصحف في السعودية، وتقلّد منصب مستشار، كما أنّه مدير عام قناة العرب الإخبارية سابقًا. ويكتب عموداً في صحيفة واشنطن بوست منذ 2017، وُصف في الصحف وأجهزة الاعلام العالمية بأنه "وفيّ للدولة السعودية" و"منتقد لسياساتها".', 'qas': [{'question': ' - في أي صحيفة قام بكتابة عمود منذ عام 2017؟ ال', 'id': '12937627845', 'answers': [{'text': 'واشنطن بوست', 'answer_start': 224}]}]}]}]
[{'title': 'جمال خاشقجي', 'paragraphs': [{'context': 'جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي (13 أكتوبر 1958، المدينة المنورة - 2 أكتوبر 2018)، صحفي وإعلامي سعودي، رأس عدّة مناصب لعدد من الصحف في السعودية، وتقلّد منصب مستشار، كما أنّه مدير عام قناة العرب الإخبارية سابقًا. ويكتب عموداً في صحيفة واشنطن بوست منذ 2017، وُصف في الصحف وأجهزة الاعلام العالمية بأنه "وفيّ للدولة السعودية" و"منتقد لسياساتها".', 'qas': [{'question': ' - كيف وصفها في الصحف ووسائل الإعلام الدولية؟ ال', 'id': '198411919509', 'answers': [{'text': 'وُصف في الصحف وأجهزة الاعلام العالمية بأنه "وفيّ للدولة السعودية" و"منتقد لسياساتها".', 'answer_start': 246}]}]}]}]
[{'title': 'جمال خاشقجي', 'paragraphs': [{'context': 'جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي (13 أكتوبر 1958، المدينة المنورة - 2 أكتوبر 2018)، صحفي وإعلامي سعودي، رأس عدّة مناصب لعدد من الصحف في السعودية، وتقلّد منصب مستشار، كما أنّه مدير عام قناة العرب الإخبارية سابقًا. ويكتب عموداً في صحيفة واشنطن بوست منذ 2017، وُصف في الصحف وأجهزة الاعلام العالمية بأنه "وفيّ للدولة السعودية" و"منتقد لسياساتها".', 'qas': [{'question': ' - في أي منصب شغل في الجريدة؟ ال', 'id': '341340964648', 'answers': [{'text': 'وتقلّد منصب مستشار،', 'answer_start': 135}]}]}]}]
[{'title': 'جمال خاشقجي', 'paragraphs': [{'context': 'غادر خاشقجي السعودية في سبتمبر 2017، وكتب بعد ذلك مقالات صحفية انتقد فيها الحكومة السعودية. انتقد خاشقجي بصورة كبيرة ولي العهد السعودي محمد بن سلمان، والملك سلمان بن عبد العزيز. وكذلك عارض التدخل العسكري في اليمن.', 'qas': [{'question': ' - متى غادر خاشقجي السعودية؟ ال', 'id': '159529139024', 'answers': [{'text': 'في سبتمبر 2017،', 'answer_start': 21}]}]}]}]
[{'title': 'جمال خاشقجي', 'paragraphs': [{'context': 'غادر خاشقجي السعودية في سبتمبر 2017، وكتب بعد ذلك مقالات صحفية انتقد فيها الحكومة السعودية. انتقد خاشقجي بصورة كبيرة ولي العهد السعودي محمد بن سلمان، والملك سلمان بن عبد العزيز. وكذلك عارض التدخل العسكري في اليمن.', 'qas': [{'question': ' - لمن ينتقده في مقالاته الإخبارية؟ ال', 'id': '199490332552', 'answers': [{'text': 'الحكومة السعودية.', 'answer_start': 74}]}]}]}]
[{'title': 'جمال خاشقجي', 'paragraphs': [{'context': 'غادر خاشقجي السعودية في سبتمبر 2017، وكتب بعد ذلك مقالات صحفية انتقد فيها الحكومة السعودية. انتقد خاشقجي بصورة كبيرة ولي العهد السعودي محمد بن سلمان، والملك سلمان بن عبد العزيز. وكذلك عارض التدخل العسكري في اليمن.', 'qas': [{'question': ' - لمن انتقد خاشقجي بشدة في مقالاته الإخبارية؟ ال', 'id': '170530085422', 'answers': [{'text': 'ولي العهد السعودي محمد بن سلمان، والملك سلمان بن عبد العزيز.', 'answer_start': 117}]}]}]}]
[{'title': 'السعودية', 'paragraphs': [{'context': 'السعودية أو (رسميًا: المملكة العربية السعودية) هي دولة عربية، وتعد أكبر دولة في الشرق الأوسط وتقع تحديدًا في الجنوب الغربي من قارة آسيا وتشكل الجزء الأكبر من شبه الجزيرة العربية إذ تبلغ مساحتها حوالي مليوني كيلومتر مربع.', 'qas': [{'question': ' - أي دولة هي أكبر دولة في الشرق الأوسط؟ ال', 'id': '795896303709', 'answers': [{'text': 'المملكة العربية السعودية)', 'answer_start': 21}]}]}]}]
[{'title': 'السعودية', 'paragraphs': [{'context': 'السعودية أو (رسميًا: المملكة العربية السعودية) هي دولة عربية، وتعد أكبر دولة في الشرق الأوسط وتقع تحديدًا في الجنوب الغربي من قارة آسيا وتشكل الجزء الأكبر من شبه الجزيرة العربية إذ تبلغ مساحتها حوالي مليوني كيلومتر مربع.', 'qas': [{'question': ' - أين تقع المملكة العربية السعودية في آسيا؟ ال', 'id': '117632944204', 'answers': [{'text': 'الجنوب الغربي', 'answer_start': 109}]}]}]}]...
```

using the following code each record is presented alone as above:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
import json
from random import randint
MAX_INT = 999999999999


def batch_to_json(fname):
    with open(fname, encoding="utf-8") as f:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f, )
        for row in csv_reader:
            articles = []
            i = j = k = 0
            for i in range(1,2):
                article_title = row["title"]
                paragraphs = []
                for j in range(1,2):
                    paragraph_context = row['context']
                    qas = []
                    for k in range(1,2):
                        id = str(randint(0, MAX_INT))
                        ques = row["question"]
                        ans = row["text"]
                        answer_start = max(paragraph_context.find(ans), 0)
                        answer = {
                            'text': ans,
                            'answer_start': answer_start
                        }
                        question = {
                            'question': ques,
                            'id': id,
                            'answers': [answer]
                        }
                        qas.append(question)
                    paragraph = {
                        'context': paragraph_context,
                        'qas': qas
                    }
                    paragraphs.append(paragraph)
                article ={
                    'title': article_title,
                    'paragraphs': paragraphs
                }
                articles.append(article)
            print(articles)
```

**This is a small text example of the data:**

```
context,question,answer_start,text,title
جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي (13 أكتوبر 1958، المدينة المنورة - 2 أكتوبر 2018)، صحفي وإعلامي سعودي، رأس عدّة مناصب لعدد من الصحف في السعودية، وتقلّد منصب مستشار، كما أنّه مدير عام قناة العرب الإخبارية سابقًا., - من هو جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي؟ ,73,صحفي وإعلامي,جمال خاشقجي
جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي (13 أكتوبر 1958، المدينة المنورة - 2 أكتوبر 2018)، صحفي وإعلامي سعودي، رأس عدّة مناصب لعدد من الصحف في السعودية، وتقلّد منصب مستشار، كما أنّه مدير عام قناة العرب الإخبارية سابقًا., - متى ولد جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي وتوفي؟ ال,10,حمزة خاشقجي (13 أكتوبر 1958، المدينة المنورة - 2 أكتوبر 2018)،,جمال خاشقجي
جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي (13 أكتوبر 1958، المدينة المنورة - 2 أكتوبر 2018)، صحفي وإعلامي سعودي، رأس عدّة مناصب لعدد من الصحف في السعودية، وتقلّد منصب مستشار، كما أنّه مدير عام قناة العرب الإخبارية سابقًا., - في أي مدينة ولد جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي؟ ال,39,المدينة المنورة,جمال خاشقجي
"جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي (13 أكتوبر 1958، المدينة المنورة - 2 أكتوبر 2018)، صحفي وإعلامي سعودي، رأس عدّة مناصب لعدد من الصحف في السعودية، وتقلّد منصب مستشار، كما أنّه مدير عام قناة العرب الإخبارية سابقًا. ويكتب عموداً في صحيفة واشنطن بوست منذ 2017، وُصف في الصحف وأجهزة الاعلام العالمية بأنه ""وفيّ للدولة السعودية"" و""منتقد لسياساتها"".", - في أي صحيفة قام بكتابة عمود منذ عام 2017؟ ال,224,واشنطن بوست,جمال خاشقجي
"جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي (13 أكتوبر 1958، المدينة المنورة - 2 أكتوبر 2018)، صحفي وإعلامي سعودي، رأس عدّة مناصب لعدد من الصحف في السعودية، وتقلّد منصب مستشار، كما أنّه مدير عام قناة العرب الإخبارية سابقًا. ويكتب عموداً في صحيفة واشنطن بوست منذ 2017، وُصف في الصحف وأجهزة الاعلام العالمية بأنه ""وفيّ للدولة السعودية"" و""منتقد لسياساتها"".", - كيف وصفها في الصحف ووسائل الإعلام الدولية؟ ال,246,"وُصف في الصحف وأجهزة الاعلام العالمية بأنه ""وفيّ للدولة السعودية"" و""منتقد لسياساتها"".",جمال خاشقجي
"جمال أحمد حمزة خاشقجي (13 أكتوبر 1958، المدينة المنورة - 2 أكتوبر 2018)، صحفي وإعلامي سعودي، رأس عدّة مناصب لعدد من الصحف في السعودية، وتقلّد منصب مستشار، كما أنّه مدير عام قناة العرب الإخبارية سابقًا. ويكتب عموداً في صحيفة واشنطن بوست منذ 2017، وُصف في الصحف وأجهزة الاعلام العالمية بأنه ""وفيّ للدولة السعودية"" و""منتقد لسياساتها"".", - في أي منصب شغل في الجريدة؟ ال,135,وتقلّد منصب مستشار،,جمال خاشقجي
غادر خاشقجي السعودية في سبتمبر 2017، وكتب بعد ذلك مقالات صحفية انتقد فيها الحكومة السعودية. انتقد خاشقجي بصورة كبيرة ولي العهد السعودي محمد بن سلمان، والملك سلمان بن عبد العزيز. وكذلك عارض التدخل العسكري في اليمن., - متى غادر خاشقجي السعودية؟ ال,21,في سبتمبر 2017،,جمال خاشقجي
غادر خاشقجي السعودية في سبتمبر 2017، وكتب بعد ذلك مقالات صحفية انتقد فيها الحكومة السعودية. انتقد خاشقجي بصورة كبيرة ولي العهد السعودي محمد بن سلمان، والملك سلمان بن عبد العزيز. وكذلك عارض التدخل العسكري في اليمن., - لمن ينتقده في مقالاته الإخبارية؟ ال,74,الحكومة السعودية.,جمال خاشقجي
غادر خاشقجي السعودية في سبتمبر 2017، وكتب بعد ذلك مقالات صحفية انتقد فيها الحكومة السعودية. انتقد خاشقجي بصورة كبيرة ولي العهد السعودي محمد بن سلمان، والملك سلمان بن عبد العزيز. وكذلك عارض التدخل العسكري في اليمن., - لمن انتقد خاشقجي بشدة في مقالاته الإخبارية؟ ال,117,ولي العهد السعودي محمد بن سلمان، والملك سلمان بن عبد العزيز.,جمال خاشقجي
السعودية أو (رسميًا: المملكة العربية السعودية) هي دولة عربية، وتعد أكبر دولة في الشرق الأوسط وتقع تحديدًا في الجنوب الغربي من قارة آسيا وتشكل الجزء الأكبر من شبه الجزيرة العربية إذ تبلغ مساحتها حوالي مليوني كيلومتر مربع., - أي دولة هي أكبر دولة في الشرق الأوسط؟ ال,21,المملكة العربية السعودية),السعودية
السعودية أو (رسميًا: المملكة العربية السعودية) هي دولة عربية، وتعد أكبر دولة في الشرق الأوسط وتقع تحديدًا في الجنوب الغربي من قارة آسيا وتشكل الجزء الأكبر من شبه الجزيرة العربية إذ تبلغ مساحتها حوالي مليوني كيلومتر مربع., - أين تقع المملكة العربية السعودية في آسيا؟ ال,109,الجنوب الغربي,السعودية
السعودية أو (رسميًا: المملكة العربية السعودية) هي دولة عربية، وتعد أكبر دولة في الشرق الأوسط وتقع تحديدًا في الجنوب الغربي من قارة آسيا وتشكل الجزء الأكبر من شبه الجزيرة العربية إذ تبلغ مساحتها حوالي مليوني كيلومتر مربع., - ما هي مساحة الجزء الأكبر من شبه الجزيرة العربية؟ ال,194,حوالي مليوني كيلومتر مربع.,السعودية
السعودية ورسميًا المملكة العربية السعودية هي أكبر دولة في الشرق الأوسط وتقع تحديدًا في الجنوب الغربي من قارة آسيا وتشكل الجزء الأكبر من شبه الجزيرة العربية إذ تبلغ مساحتها حوالي مليوني كيلومتر مربع. يحدها من الشمال العراق والأردن وتحدها الكويت من الشمال الشرقي، ومن الشرق تحدها كل من قطر والإمارات العربية المتحدة بالإضافة إلى البحرين التي ترتبط بالسعودية من خلال جسر الملك فهد الواقع على الخليج العربي، ومن الجنوب تحدها اليمن، وعُمان من الجنوب الشرقي، كما يحدها البحر الأحمر من جهة الغرب., - ما هي الحدود في الشمال؟ ال,199,يحدها من الشمال العراق والأردن,السعودية
السعودية ورسميًا المملكة العربية السعودية هي أكبر دولة في الشرق الأوسط وتقع تحديدًا في الجنوب الغربي من قارة آسيا وتشكل الجزء الأكبر من شبه الجزيرة العربية إذ تبلغ مساحتها حوالي مليوني كيلومتر مربع. يحدها من الشمال العراق والأردن وتحدها الكويت من الشمال الشرقي، ومن الشرق تحدها كل من قطر والإمارات العربية المتحدة بالإضافة إلى البحرين التي ترتبط بالسعودية من خلال جسر الملك فهد الواقع على الخليج العربي، ومن الجنوب تحدها اليمن، وعُمان من الجنوب الشرقي، كما يحدها البحر الأحمر من جهة الغرب., - ما هي الحدود في الشمال الشرقي؟ ال,237,الكويت,السعودية
السعودية ورسميًا المملكة العربية السعودية هي أكبر دولة في الشرق الأوسط وتقع تحديدًا في الجنوب الغربي من قارة آسيا وتشكل الجزء الأكبر من شبه الجزيرة العربية إذ تبلغ مساحتها حوالي مليوني كيلومتر مربع. يحدها من الشمال العراق والأردن وتحدها الكويت من الشمال الشرقي، ومن الشرق تحدها كل من قطر والإمارات العربية المتحدة بالإضافة إلى البحرين التي ترتبط بالسعودية من خلال جسر الملك فهد الواقع على الخليج العربي، ومن الجنوب تحدها اليمن، وعُمان من الجنوب الشرقي، كما يحدها البحر الأحمر من جهة الغرب., - ما هي الحدود في الشرق؟ ,284,قطر والإمارات العربية المتحدة بالإضافة إلى البحرين التي ترتبط بالسعودية من خلال جسر الملك,السعودية
"حكم آل سعود تاريخيا في نجد ومناطق واسعة من الجزيرة العربية أكثر من مرة، وتعتبر المملكة السعودية الحالية نتاجًا ووارثة لتلك الكيانات التاريخية، أول تلك الكيانات إمارة الدرعية التي أسسها محمد بن سعود سنة 1157 هـ / 1744 وظلت حتى قاد إبراهيم باشا جيش والي مصر العثماني في حملة للقضاء عليها عام 1233 هـ / 1818م، ويشار إلى تلك المرحلة باسم ""الدولة السعودية الأولى""، ولكن لم يطل الوقت بعد سقوط الدولة الأولى حتى أقام تركي بن عبد الله بن محمد إمارة جديدة لآل سعود في نجد، اتخذت من الرياض عاصمة واستمرت حتى انتزع حكام إمارة حائل إمارة الرياض من آل سعود سنة 1308 هـ / 1891، ويشار إلى تلك المرحلة بـ""الدولة السعودية الثانية"". لاحقًا استرد عبد العزيز آل سعود الشاب سنة 1319 هـ / 1902 إمارة الرياض من يد آل رشيد، وتوسع مسيطرا على كامل نجد 1921 وتسمت بسلطنة نجد حتى نجح عبد العزيز بانتزاع مملكة الحجاز من يد الهاشميين، فنصب ملكا على الحجاز في يناير من عام 1926، وبعدها بعام غيّر لقبه من سلطان نجد إلى ملك نجد، وسميت المناطق التي يسيطر عليها مملكة الحجاز ونجد وملحقاتها، وظلت بذلك الاسم حتى وحد عبد العزيز جميع المناطق التي يسيطر عليها في كيان واحد، وكان ذلك في 1351 هـ / 23 سبتمبر 1932 وأُعلن اسمها ""المملكة العربية السعودية"".", - ما هي الكيانات الأولى في المملكة العربية السعودية؟ ,143,أول تلك الكيانات إمارة الدرعية,السعودية
"حكم آل سعود تاريخيا في نجد ومناطق واسعة من الجزيرة العربية أكثر من مرة، وتعتبر المملكة السعودية الحالية نتاجًا ووارثة لتلك الكيانات التاريخية، أول تلك الكيانات إمارة الدرعية التي أسسها محمد بن سعود سنة 1157 هـ / 1744 وظلت حتى قاد إبراهيم باشا جيش والي مصر العثماني في حملة للقضاء عليها عام 1233 هـ / 1818م، ويشار إلى تلك المرحلة باسم ""الدولة السعودية الأولى""، ولكن لم يطل الوقت بعد سقوط الدولة الأولى حتى أقام تركي بن عبد الله بن محمد إمارة جديدة لآل سعود في نجد، اتخذت من الرياض عاصمة واستمرت حتى انتزع حكام إمارة حائل إمارة الرياض من آل سعود سنة 1308 هـ / 1891، ويشار إلى تلك المرحلة بـ""الدولة السعودية الثانية"". لاحقًا استرد عبد العزيز آل سعود الشاب سنة 1319 هـ / 1902 إمارة الرياض من يد آل رشيد، وتوسع مسيطرا على كامل نجد 1921 وتسمت بسلطنة نجد حتى نجح عبد العزيز بانتزاع مملكة الحجاز من يد الهاشميين، فنصب ملكا على الحجاز في يناير من عام 1926، وبعدها بعام غيّر لقبه من سلطان نجد إلى ملك نجد، وسميت المناطق التي يسيطر عليها مملكة الحجاز ونجد وملحقاتها، وظلت بذلك الاسم حتى وحد عبد العزيز جميع المناطق التي يسيطر عليها في كيان واحد، وكان ذلك في 1351 هـ / 23 سبتمبر 1932 وأُعلن اسمها ""المملكة العربية السعودية"".", - من الذي أسس الكيانات الأولى في المملكة العربية السعودية؟ ال,185,محمد بن سعود,السعودية
"حكم آل سعود تاريخيا في نجد ومناطق واسعة من الجزيرة العربية أكثر من مرة، وتعتبر المملكة السعودية الحالية نتاجًا ووارثة لتلك الكيانات التاريخية، أول تلك الكيانات إمارة الدرعية التي أسسها محمد بن سعود سنة 1157 هـ / 1744 وظلت حتى قاد إبراهيم باشا جيش والي مصر العثماني في حملة للقضاء عليها عام 1233 هـ / 1818م، ويشار إلى تلك المرحلة باسم ""الدولة السعودية الأولى""، ولكن لم يطل الوقت بعد سقوط الدولة الأولى حتى أقام تركي بن عبد الله بن محمد إمارة جديدة لآل سعود في نجد، اتخذت من الرياض عاصمة واستمرت حتى انتزع حكام إمارة حائل إمارة الرياض من آل سعود سنة 1308 هـ / 1891، ويشار إلى تلك المرحلة بـ""الدولة السعودية الثانية"". لاحقًا استرد عبد العزيز آل سعود الشاب سنة 1319 هـ / 1902 إمارة الرياض من يد آل رشيد، وتوسع مسيطرا على كامل نجد 1921 وتسمت بسلطنة نجد حتى نجح عبد العزيز بانتزاع مملكة الحجاز من يد الهاشميين، فنصب ملكا على الحجاز في يناير من عام 1926، وبعدها بعام غيّر لقبه من سلطان نجد إلى ملك نجد، وسميت المناطق التي يسيطر عليها مملكة الحجاز ونجد وملحقاتها، وظلت بذلك الاسم حتى وحد عبد العزيز جميع المناطق التي يسيطر عليها في كيان واحد، وكان ذلك في 1351 هـ / 23 سبتمبر 1932 وأُعلن اسمها ""المملكة العربية السعودية"".", - متى أسس محمد بن سعود أول كيانات في المملكة العربية السعودية؟ ال,198,سنة 1157 هـ / 1744,السعودية
```

**EDIT:**
so what I want is that my JSON file follows this format:

```
file.json
├── "data"
│   └── [i]
│       ├── "paragraphs"
│       │   └── [j]
│       │       ├── "context": "paragraph text"
│       │       └── "qas"
│       │           └── [k]
│       │               ├── "answers"
│       │               │   └── [l]
│       │               │       ├── "answer_start": N
│       │               │       └── "text": "answer"
│       │               ├── "id": "<uuid>"
│       │               └── "question": "paragraph question?"
│       └── "title": "document id"
└── "version": 1.1
```

instead, it is giving me each row as a separate list where some rows share the content and the title and should not be written again.

Comment: Your code in not indented properly. Please fix that and provide some (smallish) sample of the input in text format (not a picture/image of it).

Comment: I have added a data sample plus indented the code

Comment: That's a big improvement, but you don't really say what's wrong with the output you're getting (nor exactly how you want the rows mapped into json).

Comment: Is it clearer now?

Comment: It helps some, but it describes only half of the mapping as it doesn't explain how the fields of each row — `context,question,answer_start,text,title` — become the values of the keys. There's a reference to `[l]` under `"answers"` that has no code counterpart. Your use of `for _ in range(1,2)` in several places is somewhat questionable because `range(1,2)` only produces the singe value, `1`. I think you need probably need to simplify your question as much as possible and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to use an external library, have a look at [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

You can install it like this `pip install pandas` and use it like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv (r'/path/to/file.csv')
df.to_json (r'/path/where/to/save/file.json')

# or if you want to use the object, simply return the dataframe as json
json = df.to_json()
```

EDIT  : I just realized you have grouped data based on fields

You can modify your dataframe `df` and group your data on each column.

---

Read more about pandas groupby:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-groupby/?ref=rp

**Summary of geeksforgeeks link**

```
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 
  
# Creating the dataframe  
df = pd.read_csv("nba.csv") 
  
# Print the dataframe 
df
```

[image: dataFrame printout]

then group-by team and player positions

```
# First grouping based on "Team" 
# Within each team we are grouping based on "Position" 
gkk = df.groupby(['Team', 'Position']) 
  
# Print the first value in each group 
gkk.first()
```

[image]

This code and pictures were copied from gfg.